# Error: Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dbflow

I'm trying to import **DBflow** just as suggested in [their readme](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow#including-in-your-project). After modifying the project-level build.gradle file and trying to sync, I get the following error:

> Error:(27, 0) Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:4.1.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I'm using **Android Studio 3.0.1**, and **Gradle Plugin 3.0.0**.

Here are my gradle files:

**build.gradle** (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }

    def dbflow_version = "4.1.2"

    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
        compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
        compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle** (applicaton)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://myapiurl.com/\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }            
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

What might be the source of this problem and how solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the library to the **module-level** `build.gradle`.

Remove this block from the top-level file:

```
   def dbflow_version = "4.1.2"

   dependencies {
            annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
            compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
            compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Anyway, I thought that on an android **project**, the **project-level** gradle is the same as the **top-level** one. At least Android Studio shows it like `build.gradle (Project: my-project-name)`, while the other build.gradle is called the **module-level** or **application-level** one, as it is displayed as `build.gradle (Module: app)`